# How to leave a blank space on IF_THEN_ELSE condition in MS Word Merge

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-word, microsoft-outlook-2007, mail-merge

I am running an mail merge program, where I need to merge certain fields. I have done these in the past. Just to add on these, I have to print certain text based on the value of the field in MS Excel. For Example,

MS EXCEL

```
               <<Column8>> <<Column9>> <<Column10>>
   Record1          Y           N           Y
   Record2          N           N           N
   Record3          Y           Y           Y
```

MS Word Merged Email

Record1
          Hi,
            blah blah blah

```
         <<Column9>>
         <<Column10>>
```

Record2
           Hi,
            blah blah blah

Record 3
           Hi,
            blah blah blah

```
         <<Column8>>
         <<Column9>>
         <<Column10>>
```

But when I use and IF_THEN_ELSE, it gives me an blank space.Please advise. Thanks.

Comment: Could you post a screenshot if you are still having this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Take the space out of your document and put it inside the mail merge code (press Alt-F9 to see)

For instance:  `I am riding a{IF {MERGEFIELD Is_Mini} = "True" " miniature" ""} bus today.` (notice the space before "miniature").

The same principle applies to to line breaks.

You can also use `\b` and `\f` for text before and after (e.g., `I am riding a{IF {MERGEFIELD Is_Mini} = "True" "miniature" "" \b " "} bus today.`):  http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/word-help/field-codes-mergefield-field-HP005186172.aspx

Either method does the same thing.